# Jax-rs returning response before db operations

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I am using Rest Services with Jersey (Java EE 6)

When Client send a request to server, after some operations server send a response to client,
Unfortunately, I take too times which affect client in bad ways, so I am trying to send response to client from server before DB operations, but I could not design it. Is there any way to do DB operations after sending response. Actually my aim is that server returns response without waiting DB updates.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could probably call an `@Asynchronous` EJB for the Database updates (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html), but then you'd have to handle the case where the DB updates failed.
You could return a temporary location to the client and so that it can send subsequent requests to get the status of the DB operations (success/in progress/failed).

Comment: I am trying to do this but I took a exception on DAO, I think the entity is not working with async method.

Comment: What kind of exception did you get ?

Comment: I took optimisticlockexception, I used multithread jpa in order to use asynchronous methods, as a result I am taking An OptimisticLockException

Comment: That doesn't mean the async method failed, it means many threads modified the entity at the same time.

Comment: Did you test the application with multiple clients modifying the same data ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html. The AsyncResponse can be used.